# Store & Retrieve Button State using shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-button

I am making an application that has 2 button news and data.

if i pressed news button then display the news in listview and same as for data.

The problem is i want to store the button state into sharedpreference means, once i selected news button, after exit when i am again run the application then I want news button already pressed and it display the news data into listview.

How can i implement this ?

i am using this code but not get it ..

```
    sharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putString("pref_empId", _empid);
    edit.putString("pref_userType", _usertype);
    edit.commit();
```

sorry for bad english 
need help thank in advance

Comment: storea a boolean value in shared preferences. every time check the boolean value if true programatically press the button.

Comment: can u help me using some code bcoz i am new bee for android n doesnt worked with **sharedPreferences** and **Button State** before

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html. start here

Comment: this website is blocked in my college gateway... :( do u have some code regarding this ... 
pseudo also welcome .. plz

Comment: google search if it's allowed in college. search on stackoverflow itself

Comment: i did lots of googling but not get it yet... no problem if u dont have a solution i have to wait for sometime for others..
thanks for try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of clicking NEWS or DATA just save preferencw value as following:

```
sharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("which_list", "NEWS"); // when clicking News Button
//  edit.putString("which_list", "DATA"); // when clicking Data Button
edit.commit();
```

When ever you start the activity, just check the shared preference value of which_list as following:

```
String which_list = preferences.getString("which_list", "");
```

Now, just compare:

```
if(which_list.equals("NEWS")) {
    //    load  news  list
} else if(which_list.equals("DATA")) {
    //    load  other  data  list
}
```